# Convert Search Core Results Web Part from SP2010 to SP2013

Tags: migration, search-scope

I have just attached a SP2010 site collection to a SP2013 farm. One of the page contains a Core Results Web Part and a Refinement Web Part. I run the site in both SP2010 mode and SP2013-eval mode. The Core results webpart always return "Scope in your query does not exist".

May I know is it possible to convert it to suit SP2013 settings? Is it possible?

Thanks.

P.S. I try create a blank new site collection and add a SP2013 OOB core result webpart. It works as expected so I think the search service application is correctly setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Scope in your query does not exist` occurs since specified Search Scope is not available in SharePoint 2013.

You could configure `Result Sources` for search in SharePoint 2013 to mimic the search scope:

> Result Sources replace Search Scopes, which are now deprecated. You
>   can still view your old scopes and use them in queries, but not edit
>   them

### References

[Configure result sources for search in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115%28v=office.15%29.aspx)